# JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation [on delete]

Tags: sql, jdbc, foreign-keys, h2, dbunit

I am setting up unit tests on my application, and that for I need to mockup the database so I am not altering the actual one.

So, I am using **DBUnit** to simulate a database based on a **XML File** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <ACTION_TYPE ID="1" NAME="INVALID_CPT"/>
    <ACTION_TYPE ID="2" NAME="INTEGRATED_FLOW"/>
    <ACTION_TYPE ID="3" NAME="CLOSING_TECHNICAL_FLOW"/>
    <ACTION_TYPE ID="4" NAME="AUDIT_FLOW"/>
    <ACTION_TYPE ID="5" NAME="VALIDATION_FLOW"/>
    <ACTION_TYPE ID="6" NAME="RETURN_DRAFT_FLOW"/>

    <USER_GROUP ID="1" NAME="AKA_CPT"/>
    <USER_GROUP ID="2" NAME="AKA_ADMIN_SECU"/>
    <USER_GROUP ID="3" NAME="AKA_CISO"/>
    <USER_GROUP ID="4" NAME="AKA_ADMIN_NETWORK"/>

    <ACTION_USER_GROUP ACTION_TYPE_ID="1" USER_GROUP_ID="1"/>
    <ACTION_USER_GROUP ACTION_TYPE_ID="4" USER_GROUP_ID="1"/>
    <ACTION_USER_GROUP ACTION_TYPE_ID="6" USER_GROUP_ID="1"/>
    <ACTION_USER_GROUP ACTION_TYPE_ID="2" USER_GROUP_ID="2"/>
    <ACTION_USER_GROUP ACTION_TYPE_ID="3" USER_GROUP_ID="2"/>
    <ACTION_USER_GROUP ACTION_TYPE_ID="5" USER_GROUP_ID="2"/>
    <ACTION_USER_GROUP ACTION_TYPE_ID="5" USER_GROUP_ID="3"/>
    <ACTION_USER_GROUP ACTION_TYPE_ID="2" USER_GROUP_ID="4"/>
</dataset>
```

This is just a part of the whole XML file, but this is where my problem come from.

I have these 2 objects **ACTION_TYPE** and **USER_GROUP** which are linked by a Many to Many relationship.

But as soon as I run my test code, I am getting this error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKFA9ACTE184RNO1RS40IW6E1LK: PUBLIC.ACTION FOREIGN KEY(USER_GROUP_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.USER_GROUP(ID) (2)"; SQL statement:
delete from USER_GROUP [23503-193]
```

I know what an integrity constraint violation is, but despite I do not think I made one in the XML file above.

Does someone know where this error is coming from, and maybe how I could fix it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: DBUnit tries to delete all data from your database before running the test case, but it is unable to properly deal with foreign keys during deletion

Comment: That is exactly what I thought, when looking at the trace.
Do you know any way of dealing with foreign keys ? Or is it impossible to do with DBUnit ?

Comment: Based on your statement "as soon as I run my test code", I assume this error occurs at test setup not at test tear down.  Is the ACTION_USER_GROUP table empty at start?  That error will occur if it has related rows from USER_GROUP.  dbUnit inserts rows from the "top down" as listed in the file and deletes rows from the "bottom up"/reverse order.  What is your delete operation setting?

Comment: @Jeff The ACTION_USER_GROUP is populated by the XML file, so it has 8 rows at the beginning. 
I do think that I can't change the order of the tables (eg. populate ACTION_USER_GROUP before ACTION_TYPE) because dbUnit would'nt be able to insert the rows (because of the foreign keys).

I assume the delete operation setting is reverse order, but I am asking myself because it should'nt cause a problem of integrity constraint violation then. Or maybe the delete operation setting is the same as the insert operation setting, but this would make no sense at all...

Comment: Before dbUnit inserts those 8 rows it does a cleanup operation (which is configurable). Manually inspect the tables are empty before starting this one time, because that easily explains the cause.

Comment: @Jeff Do you know how I can configure the cleanup operation ? I haven't found anything relevant about it

Comment: Were all tables with foreign key constraints defined to USER_GROUP empty? Operation explanations here: http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/components.html#DatabaseOperation How to configure in multiple locations here (based on inheritence or composition): http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/howto.html

Comment: Did you  resolve?

Comment: @Jeff I tried, and could not resolve it, unfortunately...
I have put this task aside at the moment anyway, maybe I'll be able to resolve it later.
Thanks for your answers, still :-)

Comment: Were all tables with foreign key constraints defined to USER_GROUP empty before running the test?

Comment: Normally no, because the database should be filled with the XML I showed before running each test. But the error occurs before a test, so it happens when deleting the database to fill it again with the test data

Comment: "Normally, no" - actually, normally yes.  The DB tables should be empty before each test for a hassle-free experience.  If this is a shared DB and some tables have data, then you can have problems like this.  As you know, the DB constraints prevent the deletion of USER_GROUP rows due to the existing related rows.  So when the test starts, dbUnit issues the delete SQL but the DB prevents it.  One fix for you is can add the other USER_GROUP-related table(s) with data to the XML and dbUnit will delete the rows in it too.